# J-Soup. Retrieving text from website

Tags: java, parsing, web, jsoup

I am currently playing around with JSoup (http://jsoup.org) and have gotten a little bit stuck. I have no problems with parsing the page and getting any links that I may need, but I am now trying to get text from a webpage.

E.g

```
 <div class="mod-job-details" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">
        <strong itemprop="datePosted">Today, 11:11pm</strong>
         <ul>
             <li itemprop="jobLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
           <label>Location:</label>
              <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" data-automation="apply_text_location">
            <span itemprop="addressLocality" data-automation="apply_text_location_area">XXXX</span> 

        <span itemprop="addressRegion" data-automation="apply_text_location_suburb"><span class="mod-arrow state-arrow-right">       </span> XXXX</span>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label>Work type:</label> 
        <div itemprop="employmentType">XXXXXX</div>
    </li>
```

I am attempting to have the "XXXXX" 's found and saved as Strings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can get an Element's text with the `text()` or `ownText()` methods.  The `text()` method includes all the text inside the element (including its children), while `ownText()` provides only the text in the element itself (excluding the children).

Thus you simply select the elements holding the text you want, then get their `text()` or `ownText()` as appropriate.  In your example (checked on try.jsoup.org):

```
String a = doc.select("span[itemprop=addressLocality]").first().ownText();
String b = doc.select("span[itemprop=addressRegion]").first().ownText();
String c = doc.select("div[itemprop=employmentType]").first().ownText();
```

(If you have multiple such elements in the page, iterate over the result of `select` rather than calling `first()` immediately.)

Comment: I appreciate your help but I seem to be getting a NullPointer Exception when trying to run the code

Comment: @user3786252: You'll get a NullPointerException if the selectors don't match any elements in the document (`first()` will return null).  try.jsoup.org shows the selectors in my answer work on your snippet, but perhaps the actual document you're fetching is somewhat different.  Either change the selectors or find the elements with the DOM-traversal methods.  You said you were able to extract links, so you should already know how to select an element -- then use `text()` or `ownText()` as appropriate.